# Dynamically load javascript inside Ember View

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to run Javascript inside an Ember View Handlebars template?  I want to run the Javascript when the template is added to the DOM.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.TestView = Ember.View.create
    tagName: 'div'
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '<script>console.log("some javascript");</script><div>This is a view</div>'

App.TestView.append()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `didInsertElement` function on a view is invoked when it has been added to DOM, see [documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L803-808).

You can then access the added view via `this.$()`, see http://jsfiddle.net/NuaA6/

**Handlebars**:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tmpl" >
    hello from template
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'tmpl',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log('view has been added to dom', this.$());
    }
}).append();
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to download an external script this way? If I had one page that used the script, could I somehow load it in for use on this page only?

Comment: **EDIT** I combined this with the information here: http://madhatted.com/2013/6/29/lazy-loading-with-ember to do what I wanted. Thanks!